# How do I populate an "attr_accessor" in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-accessor

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this model with the following “attr_accessor” …

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grading_rubric, optional: true
  has_many :confidential_memo
  has_many :scenario_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :scenario_roles

  attr_accessor :roles_str

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :abstract

  def roles_str
    str = ""
    roles.each do |role|
      str = str.empty? ? "role.name\n" : "#{str}#{role.name}"
    end
    str
  end   
end
```

In my view, I would like to display the output of the above “roles_str” method in my “roles_str” text area.  I have this set up

```
<%= form_for @scenario, :url => url_for(:controller => 'scenarios', :action => 'create') do |f| %>
…
    <%= f.text_area(:roles_str, cols: 40, rows: 20, :validate => true) %>
```

but when I edit my object, this field is not populated.  How do I populate it with the specified output from the model’s “role_str” method?

Comment: if you call `roles_str` in a console, what does it return?

Comment: In a console, if I lookup my model and then call "scenario.roles_str", it does display the correct value.  THis does not display on my view, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty text area is likely because your `roles_str` is not an attribute in your database, but rather a simple accessor. To populate the text area, provide value manually, as suggested by @MarsAtomic in his now-deleted answer.

```
<%= f.text_area(:roles_str, value: @scenario.roles_str, cols: 40, rows: 20, validate: true) %>
```

The question is, what are you going to do when form is posted back? It won't be saved automatically (as there's no matching column in the table). But, I guess, it's out of scope of this question. :)